# Fill area between two curves y_1 and y_2 not sharing the same x

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have been trying to fill the area between the curves green and orange ([Filling area between orange and green line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nW4SH.png)) but without success. 
I used the function fill_between implemented in matplotlib, but the problem is that I can pass as argument x only an 1D array, whereas here I would need something like:

```
plt.fill_between([x_1, x_2], [y_1, y_2])
```

where (x_1,y_1) corresponds for example to the orange line and (x_2, y_2) to the green one.

Would you have any idea? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could try concatenating the x- and y-coordinates of the two curves and use `plt.fill`, e.g.

```
plt.fill(np.concatenate((x1, x2[::-1])), np.concatenate((y1, y2[::-1])), 'C2')
plt.plot(x1,y1)
plt.plot(x2,y2)
```

[image: filled figure]